# How to trace Collaboration Data Objects in Outlook?

Tags: excel, email, outlook, cdo.message

How to trace **CDO**  **generated emails** in **Outlook** ?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "trace"? What exactly are you trying  to do?

Comment: I would like to being alert from **spoofing** and **spamming** in emails by tracing its IP addresses or any other techniques that it has not been sent from **CDO** or **SMTP** server.

Comment: What would prevent a spammer from creating a message with perfectly good looking headers?

Comment: You are [expert](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/home.htm) in Outlook and you must know the apps or many alternate ways to trace the sender **IP**s through email.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the Received etc. MIME headers (accessible through the PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS MAPI property), but nothing prevents the sender from spoofing these headers as well.

Comment: Thanks for your respond Dmirty, actually I sent an email through **SMTP** server and recipient has forwarded that email to **IT Department** for verification and we both in the same organization that's why I am bothering.

Comment: Check to see if there anything in the MIME headers - you can see them either in Outlook (open the message, click "+" on the Tag ribbon group on the Home ribbon) or in OutlookSpy (click IMessage button, select the  PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS  property).

Comment: Yes, it is displaying sender details in [Header](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MoqER.png).

Comment: You can parse the Received headers to make sure the IPs make sense.

Comment: It's mean recipient can trace my system IP **:(** and there is no way to escape !